# Shoe lacing pattern to minimize Achilles rub

Tags: running-shoes, shoes

Tl;Dr: what lacing pattern will help prevent rubbing on the Achilles Tendon? Are there other things I need to be doing?

Last week I bought a pair of Brooks Adrenaline GTS 19 women's running shoes (primarily for significant urban walking, 20+ km/day), and I'm getting rubbed on the back of my left Achilles tendon.

For the moment I'm protecting the area with a bandage but this is not a long term solution.

I generally wear Darn Tough brand crew-length hiking socks with CoolMax (I have multiple pairs). On days when I'm not planning to walk much I might wear name-brand padded men's athletic socks. I used to tape my blister spots as a preventative measure but now I sleep with lotion on my feet the night before a high mileage day, and often put lotion on the day of and the night after as well.

Returning the shoes is not an option. (FTR I tried on a half size larger and my heel was rising up out of the shoe.)

There are guides online for various supportive ways to lace shoes but none that mention Achilles rub as a goal.

I discarded my old shoes already; I I have a photograph of the lacing pattern but they are New Balance and I'm not sure I can exactly duplicate the lacing from the photo even if it is correct.

Some clarifications:

(1) Shoe models seem to change frequently; I've never thought it was worth looking for the same exact style as the last pair. (I've been wearing running shoes for daily walking since 2015.

(2) In this particular case I walked into an unfamiliar shoe store while on vacation after my feet informed me in no uncertain terms that I was overdue for new shoes.  The person who helped me said they had two styles in stock that might work, I tried on three pairs, and off I went.

(3) I've had Brooks before, from the Ghost line;I don't recall any particular fit problems.

Comment: Hrm. Did you get the same rub from your New Balance? Why did you switch brands? Shoe fit can vary quite a bit from brand to brand, and even model to model. Once you find a shoe/model that fits, you should stick with it unless they change and it no longer works.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - Do you happen to remember the New Balance model? The ones I remember/see from when I wore NB is that they have a cutout dip at the high point in the back, where the Brooks have a dome type shape.